# How to cast generic type to Object?

Tags: java

The code below won't compile because it can't add `Task<T>` to `List<Task<Object>>` how to fix it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Tasks {

  private final List<Task<Object>> queue = new ArrayList<>();

  public static abstract class Task<T> {}

  public <T> List<T> process(List<Task<T>> tasks) {
    for (Task<T> task : tasks) queue.add(task); // <== problem here
  }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried `List<Task<T>>` instead of `List<Task<Object>>`?

Comment: @ajc2000 `T` has no meaning outside of the `process` method.

Comment: @ajc2000 `T` is on the inner static class and erroneously being used in `process`'s non-static method declaration.

Comment: @ajc2000 the type T will be different for different task, the Tasks class don't know what it would be.

Comment: You could use `List<Task<?>>`. That will accept a task with any generic parameter.

Comment: `private final List<Task<?>>` but it comes with its own problems. Also, `queue.add(..` is redundant. You can just do `queue.addAll(tasks);`

Comment: Fair enough.  How about `List<Task<? extends Object>>`, or just ``List<Task<?>>`` as the above suggested

Comment: @ajc2000 thanks `List<Task<? extends Object>>` worked

Comment: `? extends Object` is redundant since everything extends Object, I'd just do `?` as others suggested

Comment: Why don't you post your complete code. This code makes no sense at all. Why do you have an inner abstract class anyways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine Task was exactly like `List`: It has an `add(T item)` method.

If you allowed adding a `Task<T>` to a List of `Task<Object>`, then other code could then grab an item from the list, which would have type `Task<Object>`, which would let you thus call the `add(Object o)` method, letting you add anything you want, as anything is an object.

So if you added a `Task<String>`, your task now has non-strings in it.

That's why this isn't allowed.

Now, presumably, your task has absolutely no opportunities to 'add' things; none of the methods have a T as parameter, the T occurs solely in a 'get' position, in academicese, as a covariant option: For example, it only shows up in return types of methods in the `Task` class.

Java unfortunately does not have the kind of use-site variance declaration model that makes this easy.

You have two general solutions:

1. 'uglycasting': Cast things, using the 3rd form of the cast construct, where you cast to a type that has generics, or perhaps, a raw type:

```
Task /* raw */ temp = task;
queue.add(temp); // this will work, but generates a warning.
```

then use `@SuppressWarnings`. Note that this does mean you're 'opting out' of the compiler checking your work, and if Task either has a method like `add(T)` or gets one later, you get no protections, and the end result will likely be that you end up seeing `ClassCastException` errors in places with zero casts in them.

2. Redefine `queue`.

Alternatively, redefinine queue to accept covariance. In that sense, `Task<Object>` is rather useless; few to no task types you'll ever make are actually assignable to this type. Try `Task<? extends Object>`, which can be shortened to just `Task<?>`. Just like with a `List<? extends Whatever>`, you cannot invoke `add()` style methods *at all* on such a thing; any method `Task` has that takes as parameter a `T` are now not invokable*. That's a good thing; it frees you up to assign any `Task<T>` regardless of what T might be to it, then.

`List<Task<?>> queue = new ArrayList<>();`

*) Unless you pass literally `null`, which is every type, and thus also fits for an unknown bound, but that's rather useless, of course.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing mixed task types, you need to use `?`, since your list does not know what kind of `Task` is going to be passed into it.

> `private final List<Task<?>> queue = new ArrayList<>();`

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Tasks {
    // Static classes, methods and fields

    public static abstract class Task<T> {
        private T value;
        public T getValue() { return value; }
        protected Task(T value) { this.value = value; }
        public String toString() { return String.format("Task[value=%s]", this.value);  }
    }

    // Instance fields

    private final List<Task<?>> queue = new ArrayList<>();

    // Class methods

    public List<?> process(List<Task<?>> tasks) {
        for (Task<?> task : tasks) queue.add(task);
        return queue.stream().map(Task::getValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // Implementation

    private static class StringTask extends Task<String> {
        protected StringTask(String value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }

    private static class IntTask extends Task<Integer> {
        protected IntTask(Integer value) {
            super(value);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tasks tasks = new Tasks();

        List<Task<?>> taskList = Arrays.asList(
            new StringTask("Hello World"),
            new IntTask(42)
        );

        tasks.process(taskList).stream().forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```